# Illegal instruction (core dumped) Node.Js

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

I copied my system developed in ExpressJs to the production server.
My system uses HTTPS (SSL).

When the return is 400, 403, 404, or some code purposely so, it responds correctly with a JSON.

When the return should be 200, the node displayed an error in the console "Illegal instruction (core dumped)" and breaks the application.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you copied the `node_modules` instead of moving everything else and running `npm install` to install dependencies.

Update: Now after you posted your answer I see that it was precisely the case.

The problem is that some of the modules have compiled binary components that cannot be moved across different architectures. They need to be build every time so you never should copy the `node_modules` directory.

But if you do copy the `node_modules` directory or if you update Node.js in your system then instead of removing `node_modules` and running `npm install` you can run `npm rebuild` instead. (Thanks to **mscdex** for pointing it out in the comments.)

Comment: Or you can just do `npm rebuild` IIRC, which would save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, delete the folder node_modules and run npm install