# npm command line error: Illegal instruction

Tags: node.js, npm

When running and `npm` commands, I am suddenly receiving an *Illegal instructions* error. I have followed the suggestions in this thread [Illegal instruction (core dumped) Node.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159324/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-node-js), but I still get the same error. Any ideas? Examples of the error below.

```sh
$ npm start
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 37:  
1038 Illegal instruction "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

```sh
$ npm cache clean --force
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 37:
1050 Illegal instruction "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

```sh
$ npm help-search
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 37:
1062 Illegal instruction "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

**Update** I've resolved this by deleting the `node_modules`, `package.json`, and `package-lock.json` folders, repairing nodejs through the control panel, then running npm install the issue is gone. Hope this helps someone in the future and thank you for the suggestions

Comment: I bet it's cause by the blank space in "/Program Files/"

Comment: @GrafiCode, I think this is the default location on windows. I cant imagine this error is due to this. It would have beened changed / fixed long time ago.

Comment: According to the link you posted, can you try to  delete your `node_modules` folder once and then run `npm install` ? Although, half of your commands don't even rely on the local node_modules. Maybe delete the ones that you have installed globally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fixed this downloading a version 32-bit of the node by nvm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding `--latest-npm` to my `nvm install` helped me get _further_, but I still get an illegal instruction crash.